# SSRS - accessing images from a share on another server - permissions issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using two Windows servers.

The first is my SQL Server machine running SSRS. It is set up with a default installation and is happily running and serving SSRS reports.

My second server has some user uploaded images which I need to display in my SSRS reports.

The images are located in a network shared folder and are visible to the server running SSRS.

I am using a path to the image:

```
="file:\\//WEB01/uploads/Site/" & (Fields!SiteId.Value) & ".jpg"
```

When I test the report in the Visual Studio development environment the image loads correctly however when I deploy the image is not being displayed.

Is there a setting I have missed in SSRS which is preventing the use of the source?

Comment: SSRS is running under a Windows account. Make sure that this account has access to the network share.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is that the SSRS server needs:

1. An execution account to allow the loading of external images.

Or

2. Access to anonymously shared images.

The problem I have with the first option is that an execution account needs to be a domain account. Neither of these two servers are on a domain. They are on the same network but they are effectively stand-alone servers with no DC.
This means that I can't (at this stage) implement an execution account which has access to the share.

This brings me onto the next option; an anonymous share.
Lots of information on this online but most of it involves opening the guest account - this is highly frowned on. Even though, in my case, there are no 'users' on this network the guest account is a bit of a security black hole with lots of references warning against it.

I did, however, find a way of opening the share as a anonymous share without using the guest account.

1. Create the share.
2. Set the share permissions to 'Everyone'.
3. Set the folder/file permissions to 'Everyone'.
4. Open the advanced network settings from the control panel.
   Settings -> Network & Internet -> Ethernet -> Change advanced sharing options

In the All Networks section,
Turn on "sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in the Public folders"
Turn off "password protected sharing if you trust all devices in your network"

5. Edit the Group Policy

Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options

*Network access: Shares that can be accessed anonymous* - Specify the sharename you want to enable anonymous access to.

This allows anonymous sharing and allows SSRS to access the images from the share.

I hope this helps anyone wishing to allow SSRS to access images and documents on another (non domain) server or simply set up an anonymous share.